# copy-tree on global-map

Tags: keymap

The following code

```
(define-key (copy-tree global-map) (kbd "C-r") 'forward-char)
```

Immediately remaps C-r to forward-char. My understanding is that copy-tree will return a deepcopy of global-map. So why does editing the resulting keymap with define-key change my current global map?

Comment: `copy-tree` isn't a deepcopy. Try `copy-keymap`.

Comment: And why are you even copying the keymap? Just what is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: an alternate global map, so I can build/design a different keyboard scheme without committing to it. Bind it to a minor mode, I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copy-tree` only makes copies of the cons cells, not the arrays.  `global-map` is a "dense" map, which implies it has an array (well, a char-table) inside where it stores the mapping for "simple char" bindings.  And `(kbd "C-r")` corresponds to a simple char binding, so it gets stored in the array (which was not copied by `copy-tree`).

This said, you should basically never copy a keymap.

Instead just make your new keymap inherit from `global-map`, e.g. with `(defvar my-new-map (make-composed-keymap nil global-map))`.  This map will start out identical to `global-map` but you can then modify it all you want without affecting `global-map` itself.

Comment: Oh, that's so much better. Thank you.